# primefaces (3.2) autocomplete pojo

Tags: autocomplete, primefaces, pojo

I am trying to implement PF Autocomplete component (v3.2) with POJO.  Things work fine when a user selects an entry from the possible drop down options provided.  However, the scenario where a user enters some text into the input field and simply hits enter does not work well for me.

If a user simply enters some text to the autocomplete input box and hits enter, all I have to do is redirect them to a new page with 1 query parameter.  I noticed that if I hit enter **before** AutoComplete has a chance to show suggestions, then the redirect happens just fine.  Once drop down suggestions are shown, hitting enter simply clears the input box.

I would expect something like this to work just fine, so I must be doing something silly.

```
<h:form>
    <p:autoComplete id="globalAutoComplete" value="#{autoCompleteBackingBean.selectedResult}" completeMethod="#{autoCompleteBackingBean.globalSearch}" var="aResult" itemValue="#{aResult}" converter="autoCompleteConverter" queryDelay="200" maxResults="6" minQueryLength="3">
        <p:column>
            <a href="#{aResult.url}" style="position: relative; display:block; text-decoration: none;"> #{aResult.label} <br/> #{aResult.desc} <span class='ui-icon #{aResult.icon} autocompleteResultsIcon'/> </a>
        </p:column>
    </p:autoComplete>

    <p:commandButton id="submitAutoComplete" type="submit" icon="ui-icon-suitcase" action="#{autoCompleteBackingBean.doRedirect}"/>    
</h:form>
```

Converter:

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
    if (value == null || value.length() == 0 ) {
            return null;
        }

        Object obj = null;

        try {
            List<AutoComplete> results = AutoCompleteBackingBean.getResults();

            for (AutoComplete aResult : results){
                if((aResult.getDreRef()).equals(value))
                    return aResult;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("AutoCompleteConverter getAsObject Error: " + e);
        }

        if (obj == null) {
            AutoComplete empty = new AutoComplete();
            empty.setDreRef(value);
            return empty;
        }
        return obj;
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Class entityClass = getEntityClass();
        String value = null;

        if (entityClass.isInstance(object)) {
            try {                    
                value = ((AutoComplete)object).getDreRef();                    
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.err.println("AutoCompleteConverter getAsString Error: " + e);
                value = "Unable to obtain String from Object";
            }
        }
         else {
            value = "AutoCompleteConverter.getAsString(): Object " + object + " is of type "
                + object.getClass().getSimpleName() + "; expected type: "
                + entityClass.getSimpleName();
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, value, null));
        }
        return value;            
}
```

Backing bean:

```
    private AutoComplete selectedResult = null;
    //getter and setter

    public String doRedirect() {
        System.out.println("doRedirect()");
        return "entities.jsf?query=" + selectedResult.getDreRef() + "&amp;faces-redirect=true";
    }
```